# MVC Web API Search operation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm pretty new to ASP.NET Web API. I was wondering if there is an easy way to perform search operations? Something similar to /api/movie?$sortby=Title for example.

My Web API maintains CRUD operations on a single List object. I need an easy way to return a list of all movies, matching a certain criteria. It needs to be some type of filter that searches across all friends within a particular movie. So if my Movie object contains properties like "Title,Genre,Rating" etc, and I type in "Horror", then it needs to return all horror, but if there is a movie with the keyword "Horror" in the Title then that should be returned as well. The search should be across ALL fields within a movie.

How would I do this? Do I need to write a GET method in the API that handles this manually?

Comment: "My Web API maintains CRUD operations on a single List object"  A single *static* list?  While I understand you're probably trying to learn concepts, that approach might be too simplistic to really learn the important principles.

Comment: Might I note that searches are specialized processes that might require specialized store procedures and streamlined Entities or domain objects to improve performance if the dataset you are searching has many records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write your own method is quite easy.
if yo want it to be GET just start your method with that word

```
public IEnumerable<Movie> GetCustomSearch(string lookfor)
    {
        return db.movies.where(p => p.Genere.Contains(lookfor));
    }
```

so in your client side, if you are using Jquery

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    ulr: 'yourUrl',
    data: { lookfor: 'Horror' }
})
```

this works, but not sure if sintax is 100% correct

```
/api/movie?lookfor=Horror
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 4):

I did the following, seems to work just fine.

```
    public IEnumerable<MovieData> Get(string searchstr)
    {
        if (MovieRepository != null)
        {
            var query =
                from movie in MovieRepository
                where
                    (movie.Title != null && movie.Title.Contains(searchstr)) ||
                    (movie.Genre != null && movie.Genre.Contains(searchstr)) ||
                    (movie.Classification != null && movie.Classification.Contains(searchstr)) ||
                    (movie.Cast != null && movie.Cast.Contains(searchstr)) ||
                    (movie.Rating.ToString() != null && movie.Rating.ToString().Contains(searchstr)) ||
                    (movie.ReleaseDate.ToString() != null && movie.ReleaseDate.ToString().Contains(searchstr))
                select movie;

            return query.AsEnumerable();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }
    }
```

Comment: is the same as the example I gave you :/

Comment: You should consider using the standard OData operations instead of rolling your own solution.  OData is supported out-of-box with Web-API; just return `IQueryable<T>` from your Get() methods.

Answer (score 3):

To enable OData operations for a get method, return your collection as `IQueryable<T>`.  To illustrate with the example from [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22949628/131407):

```
public IQueryable<MovieData> Get()
{
    if (MovieRepository != null)
    {
        return MovieRepository;
    }

    throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFount));
}
```

Then you can write `/api/movie?$orderby=Title` in your request.

The difference between using IEnumerable and IQueryable is that the latter evaluates the query with the OData constraints applied, returning only the data that matches.  The former will load all data into memory then apply the constraints.